# How to assign an object from an array to an arrow function?

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

I am trying to assign a variable with the properties of an object from an array in my redux state. I am trying to loop through the array of objects and assign the variable when the ID of the item matches up to the ID that I am searching for.

I have been trying anything I can from nested if statements, multiple returns, I cannot seem to figure this out.

Currently, this is what I have.

```
const currItemProps = () => {
        this.props.todos.find((todo) => {
        (todo.id === this.props.itemID) ?
          { todo } : null
        }
      );
    };
```

todos is my array I am searching for and the itemID is the ID I am lookking for (both are pieces of redux state).

I am trying to open a modal on the press of a todo that has the properties of the todo. Hence I am trying to assign a variable in my modal file with all of the properties of its current todo (the object from the array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The find function expects that you'll return True when you find your item.
also, you need to specify a 'return' statement.

```
const currItemProps = () => {
       return this.props.todos.find((todo) => todo.id === this.props.itemID);
};
```

Comment: that fixed the error, however, when I log currItemProps instead of it being an object it just logs the function? I am trying to assign that specific todo that is found so I can use some of its props in the modal.

Comment: can you show me how you log it? did you try console.log(currItemProps());

Comment: Yup, that is what I was doing wrong, thank you. So when I try to call for example a text prop of a todo do I do currItemProps().text? Because now the object comes up perfect but when I try to access the property in the object I get an error that the property text is undefined.

Comment: In the current state, yeh you'll need to 'currItemProps().text' in order to access a prop. you should consider a better solution in terms of performance, I would add a new property to the state, that holds the 'currentTodo' and will update the prop whenever 'itemID' is changed.

Comment: Thank you very much, I took your advice and moved that to the reducer and now everything is working as intended.

Answer (score 0):

In case you directly want to return model

```
const currItemProps = () => {
        this.props.todos.find((todo) => {
        (todo.id === this.props.itemID) ?
          <ComponentName todoProps={todo}/> : null
        }
      );
    };
```

then you can use the same in render method like `{currentProps}`